# Using custom WindowsForms/DirectX Control in WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, directx

I want to reuse a custom WindowsForms control that was developed with dotNet2.0 and makes use of some Microsofts DirectX and Direct3D libs (DX9.0c) in a current solution (WPF,dotNet4.0)

I tried to integrate it via System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost.

```
     private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
        // Create the interop host control.
        System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost host =
            new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost();

        // Create the Signal control.
        Control_Signal myCS = new Control_Signal();

        // Assign the Signal control as the host control's child.
        host.Child = myCS;
        // Add the interop host control to the Grid 
        // control's collection of child controls. 
        this.myGrid.Children.Add(host);
    }
```

Also I had to get rid of an *"Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v1.2.xxx' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information."* error by setting *useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy* to TRUE in my app.config file.

Now when I load the WindowsForms control in a WPF application the VisualStudio output notes **"Exception of type "Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.DriverInternalErrorException"  occured in Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.dll**

and the GUI shows in place of the control the error **"Failed to initialize MS DirectX!"**
The same control works flawlessly in native WindowsForms projects. (Im referencing the same DirectX libs in both apps )

Now I'm not sure where to start debugging this error, (exception in Direct3D.dll)
Maybe its an access or permission problem reladed to WinForms.Integration?

If you need to look the Control:
http://pastebin.com/dk00vN5u

Thanks